Overriding identity tables properties / columns in EF Core 8 has no effect
I'm overriding the IdentityRole / IdentityClaim, etc.
However, I've noticed that some of these fields has no effect either in Fluent API or via attributes.
Class that overrides IdentityRole<Guid>:
public class AccountRole : IdentityRole<Guid>
{
}

And with fluent API:
entity.Property(e => e.Name)
    .ValueGeneratedNever()
    .HasDefaultValue<string>(null) // CANNOT BE OVERRIDDEN - Default is ALLOW NULL
    .HasMaxLength(100) // CANNOT BE OVERRIDDEN - Default = 256
    .IsRequired(true);

entity.Property(e => e.NormalizedName)
    .ValueGeneratedNever()
    .HasDefaultValue<string>(null) // CANNOT BE OVERRIDDEN - Default is ALLOW NULL
    .HasMaxLength(100) // CANNOT BE OVERRIDDEN - Default = 256
    .IsRequired(true);

For instance, I have no use of a Role name with the max length of 256. Building potential indexes against these tables will be improved if these values can be overridden.
What happens is I get a script that contains something like this:
ALTER TABLE [AspNetRoles] 
    ALTER COLUMN [Name] nvarchar(256) NOT NULL;

ALTER TABLE [AspNetRoles] ADD DEFAULT N'' FOR [Name];

I have not specified that it should set "Empty String" as default or that it should be 256 characters.
Some of the other tables in Identity* works. This is just one of those that doesn't.

Is there any reason for this?
Can this somehow be changed?

(Override the properties / apply new properties has no effect neither)

Maybe .IsRequired(false)?

And then IdentityRole makes a workaround to add a default value N'' which happens nowhere else in EF Core? NOT NULL and no defaults. A role name should be required and not be allowed to be ''.
